# Import Objective-C files breaks CocoaPod

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift2, cocoapods, bridging-header

**My setup:**

1) Cocoapod of Objective-C class installed in Swift 2.0 project works

2) If I attempt to import another Objective-C class, the addition of a bridging header seems to break the class imported by the Cocoapod.

I have an Cocoapod written in Objective-C I've successfully imported into a Swift 2.0 project. Everything works fine with that Cocoapod. I didn't have to do anything to get it to work--it just "worked".

When I attempt to import another Objective-C class into my project WITHOUT Cocoapods, the addition of the bridging header seems to break my previously imported Cocoapod. The moment I create a bridging header, my project stops seeing the original Cocoapod's classes.

I suspect the new bridging header is breaking something the Cocoapod set up, but I'm unable to find another bridging header in my project. If anyone has suggestions where to look for the issue, I would be grateful for them.

**Update**

I tried adding the 2nd non-Cocoapod Objective-C class WITHOUT adding a bridging header at the prompt and I get same error. `No such module 'CocoaPodClassThatWorkedBefore'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why or how this worked, but I went to the command line in my project's directory and reinstalled the Cocoapod using the following:

`pod install`

I had already installed the Cocoapod, but after adding another non-Cocoapod Objective-C class to a Swift 2.0 project, something got fouled up. Reinstalling the Cocoapod seems to have resolved the issue of Xcode not seeing the original installation.

For those who aren't familiar with Git or Github, I strongly suggest you learn it and have it implemented on your project before attempting this solution. Alternatively, have a clean backup of your project laying around in case it doesn't go according to plan.